# How to get distinct column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new in SQL Server and need to get distinct values for each column for particular table. can it be possible if yes please provide solution for the same.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: below answer provided by @vikrant More is what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped ,please consider improving the question with some examples

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get list of distinct column name for particular table. Refer below query just need to pass table name in it.

```
select 'select distinct ['+c.name+'] from '+t.name from sys.tables t 
join sys.columns c on t.object_id= c.object_id 
where t.name='TName'
```